# CSS: Simply apply a style to the first generation of children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a css style to the first children of an element. So say I have a div, with two divs, which are the children, and within each child is their own child, which are the grandchildren.

This JSFiddle, I hope is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/o8xhba9u/

```
#parent {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
#child-one {
    text-indent: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#child-two {
    text-indent: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#parent * {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

My goal is to only have the children (*child-one* and *child-two*) to only be the ones with the red *border-top*. The paragraph elements (*grandchildren*) shouldn't have the red outline. I am trying to accomplish this dynamically, as if I were to have different elements, and add new ones later and have the effect applied without having to edit the css. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: why not use classes instead of id: set `.parent` and `.child` to have the `border-top:red and` and `.grandchild {border-top:none;}` adding those classes to dynamically created elements?

Comment: I just Google'd what the difference is between using classes and ids, and I got that sorted out now. Thanks for pointing that out! Me being a pure designer (I haven't learned JS or PHP) it didn't mean much to me, but now it means more. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [direct child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6frdqs2/)

```
#parent > * {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated. I have seen instances of those child combinators in use, but I haven't ever used them myself. I then looked at W3Schools to see if they had that resource, and I did happen to find the page: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes, that's definitely a better resource. My comment was directed towards CoderMusgrove, because he linked W3Schools.